# Was the Defiant escorted back out of Dominion space in "Broken Link"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

In the episode "Broken Link," Odo needs to go to the Great Link to be cured. However, having been attacked by the joint Tal Shiar/Obsidian Order fleet, the Founders have relocated and don't want anyone from the Alpha Quadrant knowing where they live now. To that end, they have a Jem'Hadar pilot the Defiant with a device attached to the console that prevents the ship from recording its course.

After Odo's "trial," the crew seemingly beams back up to the Defiant and takes off with no further mention of a Jem'Hadar pilot or navigational jamming. So were they similarly escorted out of Dominion space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote from the script is

> Captain's Log: Stardate 49962.4. **After leaving our Jem'Hadar escorts at the edge of Dominion space,** the Defiant has returned home. But for Constable Odo, I'm  afraid the
>   journey has just begun.

So it's pretty clear that they were escorted **back out** of Dominion space, presumably with the same Jem'Hadar helmsman; Amat'igan guiding them and the same device preventing their navigational equipment from functioning correctly.

Comment: I love your smooth touch on this DS9 topik :)

Comment: @Rocket - I think this was a case of "things not seen" causing confusion. Adding another scene (that was essentially identical to the first) would have added time but without adding to the impact of the episode.

Comment: @Richard - yes exactly my thought as well. it happen a lot in all Star Treks show. and lots of the log entry covers gapses